# Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ ModelNotFoundException - No query results for model In laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following data model

[image]

I am trying to get a have a `Servicio` given a `Auth_Token` of a `Tecnico` and `id` of a `Servicio`, but I get the following error appears

[image]

This is my code

**Route**

```
Route::post('servicio/download/{id}', array('uses' => 'ServicioController@pdf'));
```

**Servicio model**

```
class Servicio extends Eloquent{
protected $table  = 'Servicio';
protected $fillable = array(
                            'RutaFoto1',
                            'RutaFoto2',
                            'RutaFoto3',
                            'RutaFoto4',
                            'FechaTermino',
                            'Latitud',
                            'Longitud'
                            );
protected $primaryKey = 'idServicio';

public function materialUsado(){
    return $this->hasMany('Material_Usado', 'idMaterial_Usado');
}

public function tecnicos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tecnico', 'Servicio_Tecnico', 'Servicio_idServicio', 'Tecnico_idTecnico');
}
    }
```

**Tecnico Model**

```
class Tecnico extends Eloquent{
protected $table = 'Tecnico';
protected $fillable = array('Auth_Token');
protected $primaryKey = 'idTecnico';

public function servicios(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Servicio', 'Servicio_Tecnico', 'Tecnico_idTecnico', 'Servicio_idServicio');
}
 }
```

**ServicioController**

```
class ServicioController extends BaseController{

public function pdf($id){
    $auth = Input::get('Auth_Token');
    $tecnico = Tecnico::with('servicios')->where('Auth_Token',$auth)->firstOrFail();
        if($tecnico != ''){
            $servicios = $tecnico->servicios;
            $servicio = $servicio->where('idServicio', $id)->first();
            if($servicio != null){
                $array = array(
                            'idServicio' => $servicio->idServicio,
                            'RutaPDF' => base64_encode($servicio->RutaPDF),
                                );
                $response = Response::json($$array);
                return $response;
            }else{
                $array = array('Error' => '', 'Code' => '');
                return Response::json($array);
            }
        }else{
            $array = array('Error' => 'NotAuthorizedError', 'Code' => '403', 'Message' => 'Tecnico inexistente');
            $response = Response::json($array);
            return $response;
        }

}
    }
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using this:

```
$tecnico = Tecnico::with('servicios')->where('Auth_Token',$auth)->firstOrFail();
```

In this case, `firstOrFail` throws `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` exception if it doesn't find the requested model and hence it could be because the model with that `Auth_Token` field is not available.

Make sure the `Auth_Token` is right and that `Auth_Token` is available in your database. You may try a `dd(Input::get('Auth_Token'))` to check what you have recieved from the `POST` submitted by the user.